# python calculate signed crc32 integer to checksum

Tags: python, crc32

I have the following string I would like to calculate a checksum for.

```
3556.5:200:3557.0:2:3556.4:84:3557.4:4:3555.7:6:3557.7:14:3555.1:46:3558.6:21:3552.9:14:3558.7:10:3552.8:194:3558.8:106:3552.7:10:3558.9:10:3552.6:25:3560.2:178:3552.5:4:3560.5:111:3551.7:1:3561.7:1:3551.6:65:3562.5:18:3551.0:103:3562.6:111:3550.7:3:3562.7:3:3550.6:4:3562.8:185:3550.5:1:3563.7:1:3550.3:84:3564.2:1:3550.2:156:3564.8:153:3550.0:82:3565.0:400:3549.7:1:3565.9:60:3548.4:104:3566.1:20:3547.2:177:3566.5:40:3545.9:1:3568.0:20:3545.1:11:3569.4:12:3545.0:71:3570.0:82:3544.9:1:3570.6:4
```

I do it the following

```
string2 = string.encode('ascii')
checksum = zlib.crc32((string2))
```

This gives me an integer of 3467096777. However, the server provider says it should be -949017128. Additionally, I tried many variants of the string and always ended up with a positive number, which somehow leads me to the possibility that my way of calculating a signed crc32 integer is wrong.

I converted the -949017128 via the following

```
checksum_server = -949017128 & 0xffffffff
```

it yields 3345950168, which is still different from mine.

Is there a way to calculate the string out of the signed crc32 integer -949017128?

Comment: actually [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) says that `crc32()` returns an unsigned value, so that is one problem

Comment: I dont' know your setup, but trying with a string as short as possible could help

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the server provider says it should be ..."? Who or what is this "server provider"? Do they have any documentation as to what CRC-32 they are using? There are many.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the BTC's price at okex. What a good time!

crc32 of zlib returns a unsigned number which is different from signed number as the API documentation; if the server check_sum is positive, they should be equal; if server check_sum is negative, there is a need to check as below (should have better solution):

```
check_sum = zlib.crc32(checksum_str.encode("utf-8"))
if server_check_sum < 0 and 2 ** 32 - check_sum + server_check_sum == 0 or server_check_sum == check_sum:
    print(f"{instrument_id}: checksum successful")
```

You must ensure the string is corrected formatted, no "0" added if you do the type conversion.

Comment: This is not a sign problem. The "server provider", whoever that is, is using a different CRC-32.

Comment: You are correct, the provider's CRC-32 gives a 32-bit signed number, while zlib.crc32 gives an unsigned number, thus there is a need to massage the data.

Comment: You didn't get the point, but no matter.

Comment: A better solution should be using the bitwise and operation to get the last 32 bits as "check_sum & 0xFFFFFFFF == server_check_sum & 0xFFFFFFFF"

Comment: You're still not getting it. The value quoted in the question is _not_ the zlib CRC-32 of that string. regardless of whether you consider the value signed or unsigned.